# I want to display the results shown in command window by clicking push button

Tags: matlab, user-interface, command-line, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I want to display the results shown in command window by clicking push button.

I mean, I created a function and when I run that function the results are shown in matlab command window.

Now I am making an interface with matlab gui and want to show that result in a textbox by clicking push button. For that i call this function in gui but getting results in command window .

Results containing numbers as well as words (about 5 lines)

[image]

How can i redirect results from command window to GUI textbox?

```
function pushbutton4_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
global E1; 
global E2; 
results=NPCR_and_UACI(E1,E2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to build the string directly in the "NPCR_and_UACI" function, set it as an additional output of the function and, then, assign it to the statictext box.

A possible alternative could be:

- activate the recording of the output on a text file using [diary](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diary.html)
- read line by line the `diary` file
- store the lines in a `cellarray`
- set the cellarray as the `string` of the statictext box

You can create a unique filename with [tempname](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tempname.html)

At the end of the process, you can delete the temporary diary file with [delete](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delete.html).

If you want to move the deleted file in the recylce folder, you should set [recycle](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/recycle.html) `on`.

In the following you can find a possible implementation of the process; to thest it I've created a "dummy" NPCR_and_UACI function and "commented" the `global varaibles`.

```
function pushbutton4_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton4 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% global E1; 
% global E2; 
E1=1;
E2=2
results=NPCR_and_UACI(E1,E2);
% Create a unique filename
tmp_file=tempname
% Activate diary recording
format long
diary(tmp_file)
% Display the output on the Command Window
disp(results)
% Turno disry off
diary off
% Open the diary file
fp=fopen(tmp_file)
% Initialize the string
res_string={};
% Initialize the row counter
cnt=0;
% Read the diary file line by line
while 1
   tline = fgetl(fp);
   if ~ischar(tline)
      break
   end
   % Increment the rwo counter and store the current line
   cnt=cnt+1;
   res_string{cnt}=tline
end
% Close the diary file
fclose(fp)
% Enable moving the file to the recycle folder
recycle('on')
% Delete the diary file (move it in the recycle folder
delete(tmp_file)
% Setr the result string in the statictext box
set(handles.text2,'string',res_string,'horizontalalignment','left','fontname','courier')
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Qapla'